# Declaring function in foreach loop

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to create a foreach loop which would visit a link from an array of links and get contents from each of the visited websites.

But when I try to run it:

```
<?php
    require('simple_html_dom.php');

    // Create DOM from URL or file
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.forgolf.cz/index.php/novinky.html');

   $titles = [];
    $links = [];
    $img_src = [];
    $paragraph = [];

   foreach ($html->find('h2 a') as $title) {

       $links[] = $title->getAttribute('href');
        $titles[] = $title->innertext;
    }

   foreach ($html->find('.item-inner p img') as $img) {
        $img_src[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
    }


   foreach ($links as $link) {
        require('simple_html_dom.php');

        $html = file_get_html('http://www.forgolf.cz'. $link);
        foreach ($html-find('.item-page p') as $p) {
            if (is_string($p))
                $paragraph[] = $p->innertext;
        }
    }
?>
```

I get `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare file_get_html()`

And when I dont include the `require('simple_html_dom.php');`

I get: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function find()`

So I am realy confused.

Anyone got any ideas how to repaire this.

Comment: Nowhere in this code do you ever declare `file_get_html()`, you just use it. But wrap `if (!function_exists("file_get_html")) { /* declare function here */ }` around it, and you shouldn't be getting the error anymore. Declaring functions inside loops sounds like a bad design, though.

Comment: Which function you are removing , function inside loop only or above one and this both ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change code few line

```
 foreach ($links as $link) {
        require('simple_html_dom.php'); **// here** comment line like **//require('simple_html_dom.php');**

        $html = file_get_html('http://www.forgolf.cz'. $link);
        foreach ($html-find('.item-page p') as $p) {
            if (is_string($p))
                $paragraph[] = $p->innertext;
        }
    }
?>
```

**Finally Code**

```
    <?php
require ('simple_html_dom.php');

// Create DOM from URL or file

$html = file_get_html('http://www.forgolf.cz/index.php/novinky.html');
$titles = [];
$links = [];
$img_src = [];
$paragraph = [];

foreach($html->find('h2 a') as $title)
    {
    $links[] = $title->getAttribute('href');
    $titles[] = $title->innertext;
    }

foreach($html->find('.item-inner p img') as $img)
    {
    $img_src[] = $img->getAttribute('src');
    }

foreach($links as $link)
    {

    // require('simple_html_dom.php');

    $html = file_get_html('http://www.forgolf.cz' . $link);
    foreach($html->find('.item-page p') as $p)
        {
        if (is_string($p)) $paragraph[] = $p->innertext;
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but when I try `var_dump($paragraph)` I get empty array :/

Comment: **Use This Code**

Comment: foreach ($links as $link) {
        //require('simple_html_dom.php');
   
        $html = file_get_html('http://www.forgolf.cz'. $link);
   
        foreach ($html->find('.item-page p') as $p) {
         
                $paragraph[] = $p->innertext;
        }
    }
 var_dump($paragraph);
?>

Comment: here code [link](https://gist.github.com/medhirajsharma/eaf1bac5ed8f7484696e515b91d1c3d5)https://gist.github.com/medhirajsharma/eaf1bac5ed8f7484696e515b91d1c3d5

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');
```

to

```
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
```

in all instances of calling this function, not only in the within loop.

Comment: I changed `require_once` to both instances but still getting: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function find()`